# Верстка диалога

Tags: android, material-design, android-dialog

Необходимо вызывать подобный диалог по нажатию на кнопку. Искал инфу по Material Dialogs  - ничего путного не нашел. Алерт диалоги на мой взгляд не очень подходят под подобный внешний вид (возможно это можно как-то настроить через стили, но верстка конкретно хромает).

Какой диалог использовать, чтобы можно было сменить фон на синий и кнопки сделать именно прямоугольными с белым фоном, а не просто буквы на прозрачном фоне?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Вот [туториал](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/180-urok-110-android-3-fragments-dialogfragment-dialog.html).